# $\rho$ and $\omega$ mesons decays

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, mesons

As far as I understand, [typical decay](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/tables/rpp2015-tab-mesons-light.pdf) for $\omega$ meson is into $3\pi$, while for $\rho^0$ is into $2\pi$. In fact they are quite similar particles (same spin, parity, similar masses).  Why this difference in their decay?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-parity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In particle physics,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rho_meson) a rho meson is a short-lived hadronic particle that is an *isospin triplet*

The [isospin of  the omega meso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_meson)n is zero

> In nuclear physics and particle physics, [isospin (I) is a quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin) related to the up- and down quark content of the particle. More specifically, isospin symmetry is a subset of the flavour symmetry seen more broadly in the interactions of baryons and mesons.

[Isospin is conserved](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/parint.html#c5) in the strong interactions, so the difference in the decays is due to this .

Answer (score 3):

The $\rho$ forms  an isospin triplet ($I=1$)and the $\omega$ is an isospin singlet ($I=0$). The [*$g$-parity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-parity)
$$
g= Ce^{i\pi I_2}
$$ that determines the odd *versus* number of pions in the  decay    goes as $(-1)^I$.